# Hotkey preventing variable assignment?

Tags: autohotkey

I know I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure out why this doesn't work.  Why doesn't hello show up in the first msgbox I know it says the variable isn't assigned if I uncomment #Warn but it is right? This is the only thing in the ahk file.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

#SingleInstance force

; Reload the script  
^!z::
WinActivate, ahk_class Notepad++
Send {ctrl down}s{ctrl up}
sleep 100
Reload
return


ADPass = hello

!5::
MsgBox, %ADPass%
Msgbox, test
return
```

Comment: Please do not deface your own posts. If you found the solution, please consider answering your own question below in case others have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Either: You make to assignment of variable while script reads rows until has encounter with any command like: Return, Exit, or keystroke/s binding (key/s::somecode), in other words - auto-execution section, or make it Your assignment inside the Your keystroke:

```
...
SetWorkingDir, % A_ScriptDir
ADPass:="hello"

; reload the script
^!z::
   WinActivate, % "ahk_class Notepad++"
   Send, {CtrlDown}{s}{CtrlUp}
   Sleep, 100
   Reload
   Return

!5::
;    ADPass:="hello"
   MsgBox, % ADPass
   Msgbox, % "test"
   Return
```